# how to remove success message in checkout page in magento

Tags: magento

I want to change the text when the user click on the buy now when and it direct to the cart page I want to change the text of the success message

[image]

Comment: i think template path hints may not work, did you tried that ?

Comment: also do you have ssh putty access ?

Comment: yes i have tried with translate.csv but not work

Comment: if you have putty, u can use `fgrep -r "was added to your" , this may work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?